# Cannot save Security Item to Keychain

Tags: swift, security, keychain

I am trying to save SecIdentity item into the keychain using Swift 3. After saving status of operation is alway 0 (Successful), but when I try to retrieve the saved one, status is -25300 (which means that object does not exist) What I'm doing wrong?

```
func saveIdentity(identity: SecIdentity) -> Data? {
    let str = "identity"

    let saveQuery = [
        kSecClass as String  : kSecClassIdentity,
        kSecValueRef as String : identity,
         kSecAttrLabel as String : "identity",
        kSecAttrAccessible as String : kSecAttrAccessibleAlways
        ] as [String : Any]

    var item: CFTypeRef? = nil

    var status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(saveQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
    // Status = 0
    let loadQuery = [
        kSecClass as String  : kSecClassIdentity,
        kSecAttrLabel as String : "identity",
        kSecReturnRef as String : kCFBooleanTrue,
        kSecMatchLimit as String : kSecMatchLimitAll
        ] as [String : Any]

    status = SecItemCopyMatching(loadQuery as CFDictionary, &item)
    // Status = -25300
    if status == noErr {
        return item as! Data?
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might consider using a wrapper like https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess - doing security code yourself can be dangerous.

Comment: Are you sure that you get `status == errSecSuccess` after the call to `SecItemAdd(_:_:)`? When I try your example I get `errSecParam` (-50) indicating that a parameter passed to a function was not valid. (I loaded a valid identity from the Keychain for testing beforehand, so I would expect it to return `errSecDuplicateItem` (-25299) – as it does if I use certificates rather than identities.)